# Find the probability a student left their phone in class

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-distribution

The question is broken down in three parts, I know the answers to all three questions, however *can only work out (ii)*. It would be much appreciated if someone can break down the working out for (i) and (iii).

**A student leaves her phone behind with probability of 1/4 each time she attends class. She sets out with her phone to attend 5 different classes.**

(i) If she arrives home without her phone (after attending 5 classes), what is the probability that she left it in the 5th class? Answer: 0.104

(ii) What is the probability that she will leave her phone in the 5th class? Answer: 0.0791

(iii) If she arrives home without her phone and she is sure she had the phone after leaving the first class, what is the probability that she left it in the 5th class? Answer: 0.154

Comment: Can you show us your partial work and thoughts? What do you know about conditional probability?

Comment: @Karl, I came to realise X obeys the geometric distribution, X ~ Geometric (p=0.25), and then I planted this in RStudio: dgeom(5-1,1/4). This turned out to be the answer for the second question. I'm quite confused on the difference between (i) and (ii) in general. In regards to conditional probability I wouldn't be too sure how to apply it, I'm guessing it has something to do with (iii), so for example the probability she left it in the 5th class 'given that' she had it with her in the 1st class. Although I believe I'm wrong :/

Comment: I should clarify I used X as a random variable that counts the number of times she leaves her phone in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have solved (ii) and need help for (i) and (iii)

In (i), it is **known** that she has left her phone, so what is being asked is

P[left phone in class 5|left phone in some class]

$= \frac{P( left\; phone\; in\; class\; 5)}{P(left\; phone\; in\; some\; class)} \quad = \dfrac {(3/4)^4(1/4)}{1-(3/4)^5}=\frac{81}{781}\; \approx 0.104$

For (iii), do it like (i) except that now there are only $4$ classes to consider instead of five.

Comment: I don´t understand why you say (iii) is $0.1054$, I know how you got that answer, however, if we use conditional probability as you did at (i) we would get $\frac{(3/4)^3 (1/4)}{1-(3/4)^4} \approx 0.1541$

Comment: Yes, but we do _know_ that she did leave her phone in one of the following 4 classes, that is why I put  $\frac{(3/4)^3 (1/4)}{1-(3/4)^4}$ instead of $\frac{(3/4)^3 (1/4)}{1-(3/4)^5}$

Comment: @ItsTrex: You are right, my brain is always addled after watching late night sports events ! Amended.

Comment: Thank you so much @trueblueanil !!

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)